# In triangle $ABC$, the Euler line is parallel to $BC$. Prove that $\tan B \tan C = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

> I am trying to finish the solution to this exercise from *Geometry Revisited* by Coxeter and Greitzer:

In triangle $ABC$, the Euler line is parallel to $BC$. Prove that $\tan B \tan C = 3$.
This diagram is included in the book:
[image]
and here is the almost complete solution from the book:
[image]

Here is my attempt to finish things off, where do I go wrong?
Starting with:
 $$OA' = \dfrac{AD}{3}$$
then making the suggested substitutions:
$$ R(\sin B\sin C -\cos B\cos C) = \dfrac{2R\sin B\sin C}{3}$$
which can be rearranged to:
$$3 = \dfrac{2R \sin B \sin C}{R(\sin B \sin C -\cos B \cos C)}$$
and then simplified to:
$$3 = \dfrac{R \sin B \sin C}{-R \cos B \cos c}$$ (and it is there  that I think I made a mistake).
So: 
$$ 3 = - \tan B \tan C$$
 Which is clearly wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$3 = \dfrac{2R \sin B \sin C}{R(\sin B \sin C -\cos B \cos C)}\tag1$$
>   and then simplified to:
>   $$3 = \dfrac{R \sin B \sin C}{-R \cos B \cos c}$$ (and it is there  that I think I made a mistake).

Yes, it is wrong.

Dividing both the numerator and the denominator of RHS in $(1)$ by $\cos B\cos C$ gives
$$3=\frac{2R\tan B\tan C}{R(\tan B\tan C-1)}$$
from which $\tan B\tan C=3$ follows.

Comment: Thank you mathlove  for your help. I still don't understand the final step: '$3=\frac{2R\tan B\tan C}{R(\tan B\tan C-1)}$ from which $\tan B \tan C = 3$ follows.' I have thought about this since your answer but can't see how it follows.

Comment: @mikoyan : OK, let me explain. Dividing both the numerator and the denominator of the right hand side by $R$ gives $3=(2\tan B\tan C)/(\tan B\tan C-1)$. Then, multiplying the both sides by $\tan B\tan C-1$ gives $3(\tan B\tan C-1)=2\tan B\tan C$ to have $3\tan B\tan C-3=2\tan B\tan C$, and so $3\tan B\tan C-2\tan B\tan C=3$, i.e. $\tan B\tan C=3$.

Comment: Thank you, a very clear and patient explanation. You've helped me to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ and $G$ be the orthocentre and centroid of $\Delta ABC$ respectively. Let $AH$ and $AG$ extended meet BC at $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

Now,
\begin{align*}
& HG \parallel PG \\
&\implies \frac{AH}{HP}=\frac{AG}{GQ}=\frac{2}{1} \\
&\implies \frac{\cos A}{\cos B \cos C}=\frac{2}{1} \\
&\implies -\cos{(B+C)}=2\cos B \cos C \\
&\implies \sin B\sin C -\cos B \cos C =2\cos B \cos C \\
&\implies \sin B\sin C =3\cos B \cos C \\
&\implies \tan B\tan C =3.
\end{align*}

$QED.$